# Passar uma lista de URL para função Scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy, scraping

Tenho um API em Python que recebe dois argumentos (URL e uma palavra definida pelo usuário) e fornece em arquivo JSON quantas vezes a palavra especificada aparece na URL.

Entretanto, gostaria de passar uma lista de URL. Gostaria também de fazer o request com o AsyncIO. Alguma sugestão ?

Segue o código:

```js
from flask import Flask
from flask_restful import Resource, Api, reqparse, abort
import requests

app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)

parser = reqparse.RequestParser()
parser.add_argument('url')
parser.add_argument('word')
parser.add_argument('ignorecase')
 
# Função que faz um GET para a URL e retorna quantas vezes a palavra word aparece no conteudo
def count_words_in(url, word, ignore_case):
 try:
  r = requests.get(url)
  data = str(r.text)
  if (str(ignore_case).lower() == 'true'):
   return data.lower().count(word.lower())
  else:
   return data.count(word)
 except Exception as e:
  raise e
  
# Função que inclui 'http://' na url e retorna a URL valida
def validate_url(url):
 if not(url.startswith('http')):
  url = 'http://' + url
 return url
 

class UrlCrawlerAPI(Resource):
 def get(self):
  try:
   args = parser.parse_args()
   valid_url = validate_url(args['url'])
   return { valid_url : { args['word'] : count_words_in(valid_url, args['word'], args['ignorecase']) }}
  except AttributeError:
   return { 'message' : 'Please provide URL and WORD arguments' }
  except Exception as e:
   return { 'message' : 'Unhandled Exception: ' + str(e) }

  
api.add_resource(UrlCrawlerAPI, "/")

if __name__ == '__main__':
 app.run(debug=True)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você fez duas perguntas em uma:

> gostaria de passar uma lista de URL.

Parece que você não precisa fazer nada, só passar a lista.

Talvez mudar o nome do seu parâmetro de `url` para `urls` só pra ser consistente?

```
args = parser.parse_args()
valid_urls = [validate_url(url) for url in args['urls'])    
for valid_url in valid_urls: 
    ...
```

> Gostaria também de fazer o request com o AsyncIO. Alguma sugestão ?

Você está utilizando o flask, que é um framework síncrono, baseado no padrão WSGI, não combina muito com `asyncio`. Os métodos `flask` não cedem controle para o loop de eventos como é requerido pelo `asyncio` e para atender a múltiplas solicitações ao mesmo tempo o `flask` usa threads.

Portanto você terá certa dificuldade para integrar o `asyncio` ao `flask`, e não terá muito ganho, uma vez que parte do seu IO não é assíncrono. Se preferir ir por esse caminho sugiro dar uma olhada no [projeto `flask-aiohttp`](https://flask-aiohttp.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) que faz essa "cola" mas não recomendo a não ser que seu projeto tenha uma necessidade muito grande de aproveitar código já escrito pra `flask` e para `asyncio`.

Caso esteja começando, e quiser utilizar programação assíncrona, sugiro dispensar também o `flask` por um framework web que também seja assíncrono. Existem vários, um exemplo que vem fazendo sucesso na comunidade python é o [`sanic`](https://github.com/huge-success/sanic), que é feito para ser parecido com o `flask`, portanto não terá muita diferença.

Comment: valeu, muito obrigado! vou testar o sanic.